# Migrating SSH servers

Tags: sshd

I have a server that several clients uses for SSH connections.  I'm looking to replace it with a new server but same address.  Naturally the new server doesn't have the old server's keys so the SSH clients are going to complain about a change in identity.  This is only a problem for the clients that are automated and use the SSH connection for batch jobs.  I'd rather not have to update each client (several of which are off-site).  Can I/should I just copy the `ssh_host_*` files from the original server to the new one?  Or is there a better option?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can copy the host keys. And you probably should do exactly that: anything else would require updating the information to the clients too.